# How to show form entries (with conditional logic) that are in the same column

Tags: database, wordpress, forms, conditional-statements

I have a form linked to a sql database. In the database I have a column called "value" and a column called "field_id". When someone send entries, the "value" column shows the values and the "field_id" column shows id number of the field.

The fields are:
-Mobile Phone number
-Promo Code

Is there a way to create a list selecting all the mobile phone number with a specific promo code?

I can't change the form input logic. It's about WPForms plugin for WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in WPForms the form entry values are saved in it's own table called `wpforms_entry_fields`.

We should have a query that would `SELECT` all the rows with the phone numbers (`WHERE field_id = 6` in your case) and then `JOIN` the rows (basically creating a single row that looks like a pair of 2 rows glued together) by a common reference `entry_id` so we can filter those joined rows by the conditions we want.

We are getting the same table under two different names by using an `INNER JOIN` so phone numbers without a code (and codes without a phone number) will not be taken into account.

See more about how `INNER JOIN` works here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

The SQL query goes something like this:

```
SELECT      phones.value

FROM        wpforms_entry_fields AS phones

INNER JOIN  wpforms_entry_fields AS codes
    ON      phones.entry_id = codes.entry_id

WHERE       phones.field_id = 6
    AND     codes.field_id  = 5
    AND     codes.value = 'your_desired_code_here'
```

What the query does:

- it gets all the phone numbers from the meta table
- it joins each number with the value of the code from the same entry (that's why we need entry_id)
- it filters the values with 'your_desired_code_here'

You can also try `SELECT *` instead of the first line to see how the rows get joined.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I don't know why the entry_meta table is empty. Below, screenshots for the wpforms_entries, wpforms_entry_fields and wpforms_entry_meta table:
https://postimg.cc/bZYcWg7K
https://postimg.cc/zLVmXBX7
https://postimg.cc/pm0bH8xy

Comment: I have edited my answer and with the correct table name and a list of columns (and your field IDs) this looks more promising now .)

Comment: I'm glad that you've found your solution!
hint: next time, you should probably use some of the other StackExchange networks, like `wordpress.stackexchange.com` or `dba.stackexchange.com/`